# ajax call for same url for different result gives first result set always

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my asp.net application , i have used Jquery ajax call to get hson data bind data dynamically to the html table.
From page1.aspx when i click list button, refirects to page2.aspx and ajax calls make, code as below,

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", '../SVC/Data.svc/GetInventoryTrimSummary/' + valueModel + '/' + valueTrim + '/' + valueStyle + '/' + type, false);
xhReq.send(null);
var jsonObject1 = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
jsonData = jsonObject1.GetInventoryTrimSummaryResult;
$('#dynamictable').append(jsonData);
```

And table is created in service.cs class with in GetInventoryTrimSummary method.

```
public string GetInventoryTrimSummary(string modelId, string trimId, string body_Style, string type)
{
    string dynamicOrderTable = "";
    DataTable dt = Inventory.dataset.Tables[0];
    DataRow[] results = null;
    if (modelId == "All" && trimId == "All")
    {
         dynamicOrderTable = FormOrderTable(dt, modelId, trimId, body_Style, type);
         return dynamicOrderTable;

    }
}
```

This GetInventoryTrimSummary methos is defined in IData.cs class as below,

```
OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetInventoryTrimSummary/{modelId}/{trimId}/{bodyStyle}/{type}")]
    string GetInventoryTrimSummary(string modelId, string trimId, string bodyStyle,string type);
```

Now in page1.aspx, if some changes has done and click on button, session will be created with new set of dataset and redirects to page1.aspx. Where i call same ajax call, as no difference in columns in table only data will be changed.

But my issue is when first if i get default value and display in table and again if i come back with session data, ajax result set is giving me the default result set not the session result. when i debugged i found that, second time GetInventoryTrimSummary method itself not getting hit and ajax returns default values(means the first result set).
What i am missing here. kind of stuck.

Regards

Comment: Is this for browser cache? I mean in network console, do you see 2nd request?

Comment: sounds confusing with redirects mixed with ajax.

Comment: I don't see the second request in console. Method itself is not getting called. All i see the the first request result . First time when come to page2.aspx, whether if its default or session value it displays properly. When second time or further you come to this page, always it shows first result. And method not getting hit .

Comment: So there must be a JS quirk, that is preventing ajax call ( 2nd request), you need to check that first.

Comment: In Chrome its working. Issue results in IE.

Comment: solved issue, added cache:false in ajax call.